# How to compress a message using c# and decompress it using javascript?

Tags: c#, wcf, compression

I have a WCF Service and I want to send a message with the least characters possible.

Are there any compression methods to do this?

I want to compress it in C# and decompress it using javascript.

Comment: Out of curiosity...why decompress it in JavaScript.  Is this an Ajax request?

Comment: I call the wcf service from a jquery coded html page

Comment: This may be a help: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jSEND

Comment: @Russell, I can use that at client side, but how can I use it at server side? I've to compress it using c# and then decompress it using the jquery. How can I call jquery method in c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MTOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889.aspx).

Or you could implement a custom message encoder and decoder, where you pass the data through a (de)compression engine. This implies you have control over both ends (client and service).

Unfortunately I don't know the answer to your updated question. You'd have to find some libraries that implement the same compression algorithm in both C# and Javascript. I've never done anything like that so I wouldn't know which libraries to use. You could try to manually implement something like LZW or DEFLATE, but that'll be the hard way and error-prone.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I don't know the answer to your updated question. You'd have to find some libraries that implement the same compression algorithm in both C# and Javascript. I've never done anything like that so I wouldn't know which libraries to use. You could try to manually implement something like LZW or DEFLATE, but that'll be the hard way and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you might implement one of the compression techniques explained [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-compr/index.html).